# How does printing works on recursions?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void wackyOutput(String wacky){

    if(wacky.length() < 2){
        return;
    }
    wacky = wacky.substring(1, wacky.length());

    wackyOutput(wacky);
    System.out.print(wacky);
}
```

When I run wackyOutput("ABCD"), how does it return "DCDBCD", instead of only "D"? Can someone please explain to me how does it print backward all the substringed versions of the argument?

Comment: Instead of `print` use `println`. It will help you to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way recursion works in this particular scenario is the following:

So it starts with string "ABCD" and works itself down the recursion chain until it reaches "D", which length is < 2.

- Then it goes back to CD to finish the method, which prints "D"
- Then it goes back to BCD to finish the method, which prints "CD"
- Then it goes back to the ABCD to finish the method, which prints "BCD"

Resulting in String "DCDBCD".

```
public static void wackyOutput(String wacky){
    System.out.println("#Start of method: " + wacky);

    if(wacky.length() < 2){
        return;
    }
    wacky = wacky.substring(1, wacky.length());

    //After the recursion method has been finished/returned the flow continues
    wackyOutput(wacky);

    //HERE
    System.out.println("#End of method: " + wacky);
}
```

The output in console would be:

```
#Start of method: ABCD
#Start of method: BCD
#Start of method: CD
#Start of method: D
#End of method: D
#End of method: CD
#End of method: BCD
```